# Bounds for $(10 \uparrow \uparrow 257) \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow (10 \uparrow \uparrow 257)$

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

A lower bound of 2[6] (Steinhaus-Moser-Notation) is

$$ M:= (10 \uparrow \uparrow 257) \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow (10 \uparrow \uparrow 257)$$

I would like to bound M in the following way :

$$10 \uparrow^a b < M < 10\uparrow ^a (b+1)$$

Which choice of a and b does the job ?

I would also be content to bound M with conway-chains only differing in the
 last number such as

$$a\rightarrow b\rightarrow c\rightarrow d < M < a\rightarrow b \rightarrow c \rightarrow (d+1)$$

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bounds which strictly adhere to your conditions would not be very tight:
$$10↑↑↑↑2<M<10↑↑↑↑3$$

A better pair of bounds would be:

$$10↑↑↑(10↑↑257)<M<10↑↑↑(10↑↑258)$$

Here is a proof for the second statement:

$1.$ Proving the lower bound is trivial:

$$(10↑↑257)>10  ⇒ (10↑↑257)↑↑↑(10↑↑257)>10↑↑↑(10↑↑257)$$

$2.$ The upper bound can be proven by using induction twice:

**LEMMA 1: For every natural number $n$, the following holds:
$$(10↑↑257)↑↑n<10↑↑(257+2n)$$**

**PROOF:**

For $n=1$ we get:

$$10↑↑257<10↑↑259$$

Which is obviously true.

Now we assume that the lemma is true for some $n=k$, and we show that the inequality holds for $k+1$ as well:

Step 1 (using the recursive definition of Knuth up-arrows):
$$(10↑↑257)↑↑(k+1)=(10↑↑257)↑[(10↑↑257)↑↑k]$$

Step 2 (using the induction assumption):
$$(10↑↑257)↑[(10↑↑257)↑↑k]<(10↑↑257)↑[10↑↑(257+2k)]$$

Step 3 (using the recursive definition of Knuth up-arrows):
$$(10↑↑257)↑[10↑↑(257+2k)]=[10↑(10↑↑256)]↑[10↑↑(257+2k)]$$

Step 4 (replacing every instance of '↑' with ordinary exponential notation):
$$[10↑(10↑↑256)]↑[10↑↑(257+2k)]=(10^{10↑↑256}\space)^{10↑↑(257+2k)}=10^{(10↑↑256)\times[10↑↑(257+2k)]}$$

Step 5:

It is easy to see that $(10↑↑256)\times[10↑↑(257+2k)]$ is far smaller than $10↑↑(257+2k+1)$. Therefore:
$$10^{(10↑↑256)\times[10↑↑(257+2k)]}<10^{10↑↑(257+2k+1)}=10↑↑(257+2k+2)=10↑↑[257+2(k+1)]$$

$$QED$$

**LEMMA 2: For every natural number $n$, the following holds:
$$(10↑↑257)↑↑↑n<10↑↑↑(1+2n)$$**

**PROOF:**
(quite similar to the proof of Lemma 1)

For $n=1$ we get:

$$10↑↑257<10↑↑(10↑↑10)=10↑↑↑3=10↑↑↑(1+2\times1)$$

Which is obviously true.

Now we assume that the lemma is true for some $n=k$, and we show that the inequality holds for $k+1$ as well:

Step 1 (using the recursive definition of Knuth up-arrows):
$$(10↑↑257)↑↑↑(k+1)=(10↑↑257)↑↑[(10↑↑257)↑↑↑k]$$

Step 2 (using the induction assumption):
$$(10↑↑257)↑↑[(10↑↑257)↑↑↑k]<(10↑↑257)↑↑[10↑↑↑(1+2k)]$$

Step 3 (using lemma 1):
$$(10↑↑257)↑↑[10↑↑↑(1+2k)]<10↑↑[257+2\times(10↑↑↑(1+2k))]$$

Step 4:

It is easy to see that $257+2\times(10↑↑↑(1+2k))$ is far smaller than $10↑↑↑(2+2k)$. Therefore:
$$10↑↑[257+2\times(10↑↑↑(1+2k))]<10↑↑[10↑↑↑(2+2k)]=10↑↑↑(3+2k)$$

$$QED$$

Now, using lemma 2 on $n=10↑↑257$ we get:

$$M=(10↑↑257)↑↑↑(10↑↑257)<10↑↑↑[1+2\times(10↑↑257)]<10↑↑↑(10↑↑258)$$

In conclusion:

$$10↑↑↑↑2<10↑↑↑(10↑↑257)<M<10↑↑↑(10↑↑258)<10↑↑↑↑3$$

By the way, the actual value of $2[6]$ is also between these two bounds:

$$2[6]≈10↑↑↑Mega≈10↑↑↑(10↑)^{257}2.79$$
(where $(10↑)^{257}2.79$ is a power tower of $257$ tens and a top exponent of $2.79$)